# Crash when trying to detect touch

Tags: 2d, android, sprites, movement, character

I've got a character in a 2D game using `surfaceView` that I want to be able to move using a button (eventually a joystick), but my game crashes as soon as I try to move my sprite.
This is my `onTouch-method` for my steering button:

```
public void handleActionDown(int eventX, int eventY) {
    if (eventX >= (x - bitmap.getWidth() / 2) && (eventX <= (x + bitmap.getWidth()/2))) {
        if (eventY >= (y - bitmap.getHeight() / 2) && (y <= (y + bitmap.getHeight() / 2))) {                
            setTouched(true);
        } else {
            setTouched(false);
        }
    } else {
        setTouched(false);
    }
```

And if I try to put this in my update-method:

```
public void update() {      
    x += (speed.getXv() * speed.getxDirection()); 
    y += (speed.getYv() * speed.getyDirection());       
}
```

The sprite moves on its own just fine, but as soon as I add:

```
public void update() {
    if(steering.isTouched()){
        x += (speed.getXv() * speed.getxDirection()); 
        y += (speed.getYv() * speed.getyDirection());     
    }
```

the game crashes.

Does anyone know why this is or how to fix it? I cannot figure it out. I'm using `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` to check if the user if pressing the screen.

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace please

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that since the only thing you're changing is `if(steering.isTouched()){` then you're likely not instantiating your `steering` variable. I imagine your error is something to do with a null value?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to risk an answer based on my past experience with the platform.

Touch events come from the UI thread, and your GLSurfaceView is running its own renderer thread. This means that your touch handling code and rendering are clashing together, causing the app to crash immediately when both threads make concurrent access to a shared variable, in this case, the bitmap/sprite or what you're using.

To solve this, either use a mutex or lock or something like that to synchronize both threads, or cache the touch events, and handle them in the renderer thread instead. This last one is how I did it, without problems at all so far.

Hope it helps.